# How to reduce queries on associated object with Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following problem.

I have an `Organization` class that returns and array of "authorized user" emails and their associated User ID.

```rb
class Organization < ApplicationRecord

  ...
  
  has_many :authorized_users

  def authorized_user_opts
    self.authorized_users.map do |authorized_user|
      [authorized_user.email, authorized_user.user.id]
    end
  end  
  

end
```

Then the `AuthorizedUser` class - note that we lookup the user via a `find_by`:

```rb
class AuthorizedUser < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def user
    User.find_by(email: email)
  end


end
```

And the `User` model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  validates :email, presence: true

end
```

This creates an extra query for each user to get their ID. Is there a way I can improve this query?

I thought about migrating the `AuthorizedUser` class to add a `user_id` field, but I'm wondering if there's a way to improve this just SQL instead of adding another field.

Comment: What is your SQL? Can you perform this action on your web app then paste the SQL from the web console into your question? Also do you have `belongs_to :organization` in your AuthorizedUser model?

Comment: I do have a `belongs_to :organization` in the `AuthorizedUser` model. I don't really have any SQL right now, other than calling `Organization#authorized_user_opts` will do the SQL call to find a user.

Comment: I meant `puts self.authorized_users.to_sql` will tell you what the actual query looks like.

Comment: Also it looks like User is a model? Can you add that code to the question?

Comment: Gotcha, I've added the User model. For the SQL it returns: `SELECT "authorized_users".* FROM "authorized_users" WHERE "authorized_users"."organization_id" = 1`

Comment: what is the relation between `AuthorizedUser` and `User` model?

Answer (score 0):

I think the addition of a user_id to AuthorizedUser is a decent choice, but if you *must* do it without, you should be able to use `joins` and `includes`:

```
authorized_users.joins("inner join users on users.email = authorized_users.email").includes(:users)
```

`joins` here is doing what an ActiveRecord association would do under the hood, and then `includes` eager loads the `user` objects in one query so that you don't have N queries for N users.

You might also be able to mess with the options on `belongs_to` which lets you specify the key that it uses under the hood. Something like:

```
# authorized_user.rb
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'email', primary_key: 'email'
```